# How can I connect multichain node with app?

Tags: javascript, nodes, blockchain

I must create an app based on multichain for a project with my university. I must use the blockchain as database and I should create an app to put information in the block. 
I’m trying to use Meteor and JSON-RPC API (https://github.com/scoin/multichain-node) but I can’t connect the node. Someone could help me? Or someone could suggest me an alternative to Meteor?

I installed multichain-node with 
       `npm install multichain-node --save` 
this created multichain-node folder in node_modules.

In my main.js i'm trying to connect with the node (that is running in Terminal)

```
 import './main.html';

 console.log("b4 connection");

 const connection = {
     port: 6744,
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     user: "multichainrpc",
     pass: "5zGVBTY7nVsnEmp3vbGq8LTbmnmjueYkiTLc5pRzE7xh"
 }

 const multichain = require("../node_modules/multichain-node/index.js")(connection);

 console.log("info");

 let listenForConfirmations = (txid) => {
     console.log("WAITING FOR CONFIRMATIONS")

     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var interval = setInterval(() => {

             getConfirmations(txid)
             .then(confirmations => {
                 if(confirmations > 0){
                     clearInterval(interval);
                     return resolve()
                 }
             })
             .catch(err => {
                 return reject(err);
             })

         }, 5000)
     })
 }

 let getConfirmations = async (txid) => {
     let res = await multichain.getWalletTransaction({
         txid: txid
     })
     return res.confirmations;
 }

 let startTests = () => {
     const state = {};
     console.log("Running Tests")

     console.log("TEST: GET INFO")
     multichain.getInfo((err, res) => {
         console.log(res);
     })
 }

 startTests()
```

This is the error in Chrome console:

[image: Chrome Console Errors]

Comment: Can you show what settings and code you've attempted to connect to the node?

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and show your [mcve], and tell us what result you get, including errors or messages.

Comment: @Yserbius i added code and errors.

Comment: @Gabriele can you show your Meteor and multichain configuration and how you started them up?